# How to rezise root partition on Arch Linux vmware

Tags: arch-linux, partition, gnome, lvm

So i am trying to add a desktop environment to my Arch Linux. When I try to install gnome, it won't let me install as I need more space on '/'. How do I resize it (on the command line?) I am using LVM and something non-UEFI.

Comment: What is the result of the commands `vgs`, `lvs`?

Comment: I realized that I should just remake it. I broke it trying to fix it myself anyway